# Meta questions not editable?

Tags: support

The Edit link for Meta questions is grayed out and not clickable. Is this related to a Reputation level? For reference, I only wanted to add a missing tag.

---

EDIT: Examples of questions with that issue:

- [Unclaimed bounties](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1153/unclaimed-bounties)
- [Awarding bounty after it expires](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/awarding-bounty-after-it-expires)
- [How can we encourage people to use bounties?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/645/how-can-we-encourage-people-to-use-bounties)
- [Is there a formatting guide that must be followed?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3086/is-there-a-formatting-guide-that-must-be-followed)

I also can't edit the Answers. I'm really starting to think it's "normal", possibly rep-based.

Comment: Which meta question? All of them?

Comment: Questions I did not create: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1153/unclaimed-bounties, http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/awarding-bounty-after-it-expires and http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/645/how-can-we-encourage-people-to-use-bounties. This recent one also can't be edited: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3086/is-there-a-formatting-guide-that-must-be-followed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is correct, you need 2000 rep to do that per 
[Help Center > Privileges > edit questions and answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)

Comment: So I take it you can't even suggest edits in Meta?

Comment: no, you can't..